# Embedding an ImageView event handler>>>not working

Tags: java, javafx, imageview

I'm a beginner java student.  I am trying to write a simple program that will display a locally saved image when button is clicked.  The picture will not load. Code is shown below.  Any help is appreciated.  Please bear in mind my skill level.

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class PhotoViewer extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Text txtHeading = new Text("Click to see the picture");
        txtHeading.setFont(new Font(20));
        HBox paneTop = new HBox(txtHeading);
        paneTop.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));

        Button btn1 = new Button("Picture");
        btn1.setPrefWidth(80);
        btn1.setOnAction(e -> btn1_Click());

        HBox paneBottom = new HBox(btn1);

        VBox pane = new VBox(paneTop, paneBottom);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Picture Choice");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void btn1_Click() {
        Image img = new Image("file:c:\\users\\sandy\\pictures\\IMG_0127.jpg");
        ImageView iview1 = new ImageView(img);
        iview1.setFitWidth(300);
        iview1.setFitHeight(300);
        iview1.setPreserveRatio(true);

        BorderPane bpane1 = new BorderPane();
        bpane1.setCenter(iview1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is adding the `BorderPane` to which you added your `ImageView` to a node that is part of the scene. The easiest way is to add it to the `VBox pane`. Then you need to padd `pane` to the event handler:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Text txtHeading = new Text("Click to see the picture");
    txtHeading.setFont(new Font(20));
    HBox paneTop = new HBox(txtHeading);
    paneTop.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));

    Button btn1 = new Button("Picture");
    btn1.setPrefWidth(80);

    HBox paneBottom = new HBox(btn1);

    VBox pane = new VBox(paneTop, paneBottom);
    pane.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));

    btn1.setOnAction(e -> btn1_Click(pane));


    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Picture Choice");
    primaryStage.show();
}

public void btn1_Click(VBox parent) {
    Image img = new Image("file:c:\\users\\sandy\\pictures\\IMG_0127.jpg");
    ImageView iview1 = new ImageView(img);
    iview1.setFitWidth(300);
    iview1.setFitHeight(300);
    iview1.setPreserveRatio(true);

    BorderPane bpane1 = new BorderPane();
    bpane1.setCenter(iview1);
    parent.getChildren().add(bpane1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  This seems to make sense.  However, I now get  the following error:                                                                                     Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException at PhotoViewer.btn1_Click(PhotoViewer.java:54) at PhotoViewer.lambda$0(PhotoViewer.java:30)